# How to return a list of objects from soap webservice with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, soap, savon

I'm using Savon to access a soap webservice, but I can only ever return a single result, when what I want is an array of results.

Here is my call:

response = client.call(:get_events,  message: { username: "xxxx", password: "xxxxxxxx", company_code: "12TCE" })

I want 'response' to return all records with the company_code of "12TCE" and for me to be able to output them all doing something like:

response.to_hash[:get_events_response].each do |a|
a[:return][:item][:name]
end

How can I return all records and output as desired?

UPDATE 1:

This is the link to the wsdl: http://www.brrmedia.co.uk/webservices/event/index.php?wsdl

This is the response I get:

```
HTTPI POST request to www.brrmedia.co.uk (httpclient)
SOAP response (status 200)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://www.brrmedia.co.uk/webservices/event" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getEventsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.brrmedia.co.uk/webservices/event">
      <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:objEvent[1]">
        <item xsi:type="tns:objEvent">
          <id xsi:type="xsd:int">119466</id>
          <name xsi:type="xsd:string">blur Group - 2000 projects milestone</name>
          <summary xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
          <location xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
          <date xsi:type="xsd:string">2013-12-17 11:30</date>
          <link xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.brrmedia.co.uk/event/119466/partner/brrsoap</link>
          <company xsi:type="tns:objCompany">
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">blur Group</name>
            <codes xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:objCompanyCode[1]">
              <item xsi:type="tns:objCompanyCode">
                <code xsi:type="xsd:string">BLUR</code>
                <collection xsi:type="xsd:string">London Stock Exchange (AIM)</collection>
              </item>
            </codes>
            <website xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.blurgroup.com/</website>
            <category xsi:type="xsd:string">Technology</category>
          </company>
          <presenter xsi:type="tns:objPresenter">
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string"> Philip Letts</name>
            <image xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.brrmedia.co.uk/getimage/id/31215</image>
          </presenter>
          <media xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:objMediaItem[3]">
            <item xsi:type="tns:objMediaItem">
              <src xsi:type="xsd:string">http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brr-streamguys/files/BLUR/blur20131217.pdf</src>
              <duration xsi:type="xsd:string">00:00:00</duration>
              <filesize xsi:type="xsd:string">380</filesize>
              <media_type xsi:type="xsd:string">pdf</media_type>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:objMediaItem">
              <src xsi:type="xsd:string">http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brr-streamguys/files/BLUR/BLUR20131217</src>
              <duration xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <filesize xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <media_type xsi:type="xsd:string">presimages</media_type>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:objMediaItem">
              <src xsi:type="xsd:string">http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brr-streamguys/files/BLUR/BLUR20131217editv1.mp3</src>
              <duration xsi:type="xsd:string">00:07:54</duration>
              <filesize xsi:type="xsd:string">5557</filesize>
              <media_type xsi:type="xsd:string">audio</media_type>
            </item>
          </media>
          <type xsi:type="xsd:string">audio</type>
          <height xsi:type="xsd:int">900</height>
          <width xsi:type="xsd:int">680</width>
        </item>
      </return>
    </ns1:getEventsResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: how does the wsdl look like? have you tried it with SOapUI? how does the logging look like? you need to think more before you send a question like that. then we can help.

Comment: I've tried unsuccessfully tried to get the desired response with SOapUI.  I've updated question with more info.  Is there anything specific you'd need to see?

Comment: I cannot find an array in the response you present. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place. If there is no array in the response, you won't be able to convert it into an array on the client side. Perhaps you should check the publisher of the interface on how to get the array. Did it work in another language, eg. PHP, for you?